# How to restart a C# console app in the same Cmd window?

Tags: c#, cmd, console, restart

I have a need for restarting a console app I'm writing and have written code to restart it using two different methods.

```
Application.Restart();
return;
```

as well as

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(System.Windows.Application.ResourceAssembly.Location, string.Join(" ", args));
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
return;
```

These snippets of code run inside the Main() method and the app exits immediately after starting the new process. Both work but both open a new Cmd window.

Is there some way to have the new process continue using the same Cmd window after the first one ends?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633796/start-a-process-in-the-same-console

Comment: If you start a command prompt first, and run your program by typing it's name into the command prompt, the window should stay open... but you might still get a new window.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happens. The current window stays open but the new instance starts in a new window.

Comment: Thanks @codroipo that solves it. Will mark my question as a duplicate.