# What goes into deciding whether a process starts in the same console BESIDES UseShellExecute = false

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, console

Looking at [Start a process in the same console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633796/start-a-process-in-the-same-console) as well as other resources, it sounds like the only thing you should need to do to get a process to start in the same console as the current process is to set `UseShellExecute` to false.

However, I am finding that this does not always work. For example, I created an NUnit test and ran it from visual studio:

```
[Test]
public void ConsoleTest()
{
            var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\netstat.exe", "-n")
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
            };

            p.Start();
            var hasSameConsole = HasSameConsole(p.Id);
            Assert.IsFalse(p.HasExited, "process was still running when we did the console test");
            Assert.IsTrue(hasSameConsole); // this fails
}

private static bool HasSameConsole(int processId)
{
            uint processListCount = 1;
            uint[] processIdListBuffer;
            do
            {
                processIdListBuffer = new uint[processListCount];
                processListCount = GetConsoleProcessList(processIdListBuffer, processListCount);
            }
            while (processListCount > processIdListBuffer.Length);

            return processIdListBuffer.Take((int)processListCount)
                .Contains(checked((uint)processId));
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetConsoleProcessList(uint[] lpdwProcessList, uint dwProcessCount);
```

What is the cause of this behavior?

**EDIT:**

To make sure that the current process has a console, I added:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
prviate static extern bool AllocConsole();

...

// before starting the child process
Assert.IsTrue(AllocConsole());
```

However, I'm still not seeing the console be inherited by the child process.

Comment: Did you check if test had console to start with?

Comment: You're not checking whether `GetConsoleProcessList` returns 0, which will be the case if the current process has no console.

Comment: @eryksun good call. I added a check and indeed it was returning 0. BUT then I added a call to AllocConsole() before running the process. This works, and now the list count is 1. However, the console still isn't being inherited.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov see my edits

Comment: Wait a bit for the process to start and attach to the console. Also, have netstat loop on an interval, so it's still running when you check. Manually `Kill()` it after checking.

Comment: @eryksun I tried adding a 1-second sleep after process start but it does not change the result. Can you explain why `Kill()` would matter?

Comment: I suggested `Kill` after checking to go along with running netstat in a endless loop (e.g. `netstat -n 1`). That way you can wait long enough to know it has had ample time to attach to the console, with the assurance that it hasn't already exited.